# Is there an issue passing data using window.name in a Phonegap application?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm creating a phonegap application for multiple platforms (specifically, Playbook and iPad) that requires passing a large amount of information between its pages. From what I've read on the subject, I have too much to pass through the URL. I also can't do anything server-side to pass the information. The only option I've found would be to use the window.name property. However, everything I've read was very clear on the fact that you should not do that, due to the security risks involved. In a phonegap application, do those risks still exist? Alternatively, is there a better way to pass information between pages in Phonegap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localStorage is tailor made for what you are looking to do:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

Comment: Ooh, thanks! I didn't find that! This may be a stupid question, but we've had problems with it before. Will it work with tablets? It just says iPhone and Blackberry. Will is work on Playbooks and iPads? I assume it would, but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Yes, it is built in HTML5 functionality. It will work on every webkit based browser which is on your iPhone, iPad, BB, Playbook and Android devices.